# Speeding up an OSGI application's startup time

Tags: java, osgi, startup, equinox, osgi-bundle

I inherited a program that runs on OSGI. It takes about 15 seconds to start it up. It is just a java se desktop program. It spends half of its time initializing and then the second half loading plugins. I am working with the original developer on pruning unneeded bundles, but is there anything I can try? I am not turning up anything on Google.

Also I am using Equinox.

Comment: 15 seconds seems to be a lot. Do you have such a complex application? Is your CPU usage working 100% during starting up? Did you try to profile the application to find hot methods? E.g. you could try shutting down the OSGi container via console and do a profiling (for example with JVisualVM) when you start the OSGi container again via the console.

Comment: Almost invariably this is caused by Bundle Activators that do some network lookup. Just disable your network and see what fails.

Comment: That is a great idea, but unfortunately I cannot disable the network on my dev-box. I think I am just going to have to live with this for now.